# Why doesn't my CSS pop-up message span the width of the browser viewport in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, popup, message

I have this for my popup message (like stackoverflow has, you know the "You have earned a badge" "You have new responses" at the top):

```
#message {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 105;
    background-color:blue;
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
  height: 26px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Now, I am not good with CSS, but I would like to have an fix for IE. With Firefox, the message box spans the viewport from left to right:

```
+------------------------------------+
|<---------------------------------->|
|                                    |
```

...but with IE it reaches the left edge of the viewport, but then it stops like 2 cm before the right edge:

```
+------------------------------------+
|<---------------------------------> |
|                                    |
```

Any idea why?

Comment: What's the margin of the BODY tag? Maybe something like this: `BODY { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Comment: Make sure your #message div is not inside any other container except the BODY.

Comment: It is inside another <div>? It need to be, because i have a js script that puts the <div message in there.. Is there another way to solve it

Comment: Pygorex, please make your comment into an answer so folks searching later can find it easier.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If the body (or some other relevant container) *might* scroll — that is, if it does not have the style `overflow: hidden` — then IE will (often, at least) pre-reserve space on the right hand side for the scrollbar.  Try setting `overflow: hidden` on your `body` tag just to see what happens - that may not be what you need to do overall to get the problem to go away.

Answer (score 0):

try setting right:0 aswell as left:0. You can simultaneously set left and right when positioning absolute.